# Listenable Future callback is heavily delayed

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, guava, completable-future

My callbacks on my Guava listenable futures are delayed. I'm writing an application that essentially has a thread pool and once the "long running task" is complete, then I have a success callback like so:

```
          ListenableFuture<Boolean> listenableFuture = service.submit(() -> publish(eventName, record, producer));
          Futures.addCallback(listenableFuture, new FutureCallback<>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
              System.out
                  .println(LocalTime.now() + " Task completed successfully with result: " + result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
              System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + " Task failed with result: " + t.getMessage());
            }
          }, service);
```

My initialization of the service looks like the following:

```
    executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, poolSize,
        0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(targetAmount),
        handler);
    service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(executorService);
```

Within my long-running task I execute, I print when the network request is successful.

```
  private Boolean publish(String eventName, ProducerRecord rec, Producer producer) {
      AtomicBoolean failed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
      producer.send(rec, (metadata, exception) -> {
        if (exception != null) {
          failed.set(true);
        } else {
           System.out.println("The network request is successful");
        }
      });

      if (failed.get() == true) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
  }
```

### Problem

If I set the threadpool to process 1MM things, I will see 1MM `The network request is successful` before I see a single callback println statement get fired. Why is this the case?

Comment: Don't the callbacks run on the same executor, hence they would be queued behind the actual network request tasks? Just a bit of speculation I'm afraid.

Comment: what is 1MM? 1 trillion?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Another way of saying 1 million (1 thousand thousands)

Comment: then why not 1M or 1KK?

Comment: questions of kind "how to fix" should be formed as finished compilable and executable code snippets. Otherwise, the r\problem can be hidden in the absent part of the code, adn we are unable to fix it.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov 1MM is a common unit. Also, this is a very well compiled example.. I don't know what you want you would expect? Me to put the answer itself?

Comment: btw M is milli (milli millis) thousand thousands.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture-com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) for Futures.addCallback states, the callback is run in the executor. Your callback is only going to be run after all of the other queued elements have completed. To fix this you could create a separate executor to just execute the callbacks, or since it seems you control the pool constructor you could create a [priority queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) instead of a LinkedBlockingQueue as the task queue and prioritize your callbacks.